# Html5 for mobile - swipe scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, mobile

I'm working on a few html5 screens which will be embedded inside native mobile apps (for ios and android).

I obviously don't want to reinvent things here, and would like to use a stable framework on the javascript side of things.
I tried using JQuery Mobile but it is way more than I need, plus they kind of force you to do things their way.

All I need is to have an element which can be (vertically) scrolled by swiping (without visible scrollbars), but I couldn't find how that can be done with JQM easily (without all of their widgets, themes and defaults).

I also tried [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) but it did not work at all.

Any ideas what will be the best approach?
Thanks.

**Update**

I found this jquery plugin which does what I need: https://github.com/ifightcrime/touch-scroll

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` which uses the native inertia scrolling built into the phone. Works really well. There is a scrollbar, but I'm sure some clever positioning could solve that.

More info here: http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/
And here: http://fioravengi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/implications-of-ios-5-webkit-overflow.html

Hope that helps :)

**edit:** Sorry, just realised you need it to work on android. I doubt this does. For iOS though this works a treat. So, half an answer!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check further into this, I wasn't aware of this at all. I also added `ios` and `android` tags to the question to make things more clear.

Comment: FYI, momentum scrolling works on android 3+, but there's no -webkit style property for turning it on/off.